# Flex ComboBox button height

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

I am creating a flex plugin for Illustrator CS6 and it needs to be compact.  I have a ComboBox that is a little taller than I like.  If I set the height, the drop-down button doesn't seem to be affected.  In fact, I can't make the button any shorter than 23 pixels, although the rest of the control is sized correctly.

Is there a trick to sizing the drop-down button short of writing a new control?

Comment: Are you using a Spark ComboBox or an MX ComboBox?  In Spark you should be able to control this with a custom skin.  I think there is a custom button skin for the down arrow.  It may have a hard coded size or something similar.

Comment: It's a Spark ComboBox.  I'll take a look at the skin.  Thanks for the suggestion.